# JRuby failing to install gem dependency cool.io

Tags: rvm, jruby

I'm new with ruby and I'm facing a problem with installing some gems required by a ruby project I'm trying to build

I have installed rvm and I try to run the following command to fetch, if I understand well the missing dependencies of my project

```
$> jruby --1.9 /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/bin/bundle install
```

And I fall into the following exception:

```
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake 0.9.6
Installing addressable 2.3.6

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.12-dev/bin/jruby extconf.rb 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.12/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h

extconf failed, uncaught signal 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.12/gems/cool.io-1.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.12/extensions/universal-java-1.7/1.9/cool.io-1.2.4/gem_make.out
```

My version is

```
$> ruby -v
jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392) 2014-04-15 643e292 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_60-b19 [linux-amd64]
```

I've seen on similar posts that a dev package is missing but how do I install it via rvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRuby's native extension support was an experiment and is not recommended to be used.
All of your gems that use MRI's native extension API might just no longer work on JRuby, usually mature gems provide a JRuby specific alternative but that is not always the case.

**cool.io** gem seems to be one of those (will only work on MRI as it needs to build it's native extension)